# Copied Xpath from Chrome but still unable to locate element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

Here's the relevant code:

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, WebDriverException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--incognito')
options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/path/to/chromedriver", options=options)

driver.get("https://uk.eu-supply.com/ctm/supplier/publictenders?B=UK")

#Check Next Page button to see if it's clickable after scraping each page
els = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='pagination ctm-pagination']/ul[1]/li[last()]/a"))).get_attribute("data-current-page")


for i in range(int(els)):
    # Wait for the page to load
    time.sleep(10)
    # Assign all page data to variable
    html = driver.page_source
    # Pass it on to BS for parsing
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    # The main page presents all tenders in table form, so go through each row of the table
    for tr in bs.find_all("tr"):
        # Check each row for table data tag
        for td in tr.find_all("td"):
            # check each set of table data for an a link, which will be the link to the individual tender page
            for link in td.find_all('a'):

                # Extract link from each link listing
                relativeLink = link.get('href')

                # Use regex to find the PID in the relativeLink
                # Assign variable to PID
                PID = re.search('PID=(.+?)&PP', relativeLink)

                if PID:
                    found = PID.group(1)
                    # Stick the PID into a URL and assign a variable 
                    # This creates a link to each individual tender
                    tenderLink = 'https://uk.eu-supply.com/ctm/Supplier/PublicPurchase/' + found + '/0/0?returnUrl=ctm/Supplier/publictenders&b=UK' 
                    # print(tenderLink)

                    try:
                        # Try to open the tender link we just created
                        tender = urlopen(tenderLink)
                        # Create object from all the data on the tender page and pass it to BS
                        tenderInfo = BeautifulSoup(tender, 'lxml') 
                    except:
                        # If the link won't open, there is a problem.
                        print("I was not able to open the link to this tender.")

                    buyerName = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tenderInfoSection"]/div[1]/div[2]/p[1]/text()')
                    if buyerName:
                        print('Buyer name: ' + buyerName)
                    else:
                        pass
```

What I want to get is the first line (and subsequent lines, but I'll deal with that later) of the buyer contact info if it exists. An example URL where it does exist is [here](https://uk.eu-supply.com/ctm/Supplier/PublicPurchase/34180/0/0?returnUrl=ctm/Supplier/publictenders&b=UK). I just want the line that says 'United Kingdom Atomic Energy Authority'. Nothing else after that.

The xpath in the code above I got from Chrome Developer tools, but it gives me this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="tenderInfoSection"]/div[1]/div[2]/p[1]/text()"}
```

I get the same error when I try the absolute xpath as well. How could it be giving me this error if I got the xpath directly from Chrome? I've tried coming up with my own xpath but nothing worked. In fact I am constantly having trouble with xpaths copied from Chrome... they never seem to work when I use them.

Answer (score 1):

The element which you are trying to search using **id=tenderInfoSection** is on the page of particular tender and not on the main page which you are opening. Whatever you want to **scrape** is mostly available in the table of the main URL which you have used.

Try the below approach using [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io) and [beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). By using this 2 packages less code is needed, reliable, fast and accurate.

In the below script :-

1. First it is extracting all the html code using **GET** request.
2. Then passing it to **BS4** for **HTML** parsing using **lxml**.
3. Finding all the  tags as all the data is available in the table tag.
4. Finally iterating on each and every  tag to get the data of tender like ID, reference, name , process , buyers etc. and printing on the console window.

> I have created the passed URL dynamic where you can pass the country code(in **country_code** variable) and it will start fetching the data for that country.

```
import requests
from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

    def scrape_tender_data():

    country_code = 'UK' #country code
    URL = 'https://uk.eu-supply.com/ctm/supplier/publictenders?B=' + country_code #dynamic URL

    print('URL created: ', URL)
    url_result = requests.get(URL,verify=False) # requesting data in the from of HTML
    soup_result = bs(url_result.text,'lxml') #parsing extracted HTML
    fetch_all_tr = soup_result.findAll('tr') #searching all tr's

    for idx,tr in enumerate(fetch_all_tr): # traversing over all tr's
        if idx > 0:
            print('-' * 100)
            for idx,data in enumerate(tr):
                if idx % 2 == 1:                    
                    print(data.text.strip())
            print('-' * 100)

   scrape_tender_data()
```

Comment: You're right about the page, except I left out a number of loops I'm running in order to get to the individual tender page just so my question wasn't too long. Sorry if that was unclear. I don't need a dynamic country code because this will only be for UK tenders. I will edit my code above to show the loops.

Comment: just for my own learning, what does the line about if idx % 2 == 1 show? I understand you're getting the modulus, I just don't understand why you need it. Why doesn't it leave out index positions that don't have a modulus of 1?

Comment: If you will debug you will get to know that all the data like I’d, reference, buyers info and all are at odd index positions. So, I have just filtered out and extracting information which is needed for your purpose because on even indexes there are only next line ‘\n’ is available.

Comment: Even though if you just want to scrap data for UK this will work for other countries as well in future just in case if you want to scrap any other country. Also if you want the URL of tenders you can fetch it that thing from the above code only and then you can do a get requests for each URL and extract the information